# debug directory does not exist error running React-native's AwsomeProject

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to create a react-native android app following react-native "Getting started" [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) but when I try to run it both through CLI and with Android studio it gives me this error:

```
 A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\AwsomeProject\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug: error: directory does not exist.
```

I tried deleting the build folder, cleaning the project and re-running it but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your situation right:

- There is absolutely no issue in your `Java` and `XML`.
- Your project built just fine before this.
- You tried to remove the build cache.

In addition to above you should remove the `.gradle` directory as well.

Unfortunately, some `react-native` modules have their own build directory inside the `node_modules/` directory, so it is possible that you didn't clear the build cache for them.

Of course, it's really hard to go into each module and remove the build cache manually each time, but fortunately, you can change this behavior by adding to `build.gradle` file something like below:

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    buildDir = "${rootProject.rootDir}/.build/${project.name}"
}
```

> **Note:** This tells *gradle* to use the same build directory for all projects.
>
> I prefer "`.build`" as build directory but you may want to change that to "`build`" in above.

Comment: Updated! (the `.gradle` directory should be removed too).